# malloc inside threaded routine

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

Does the following code excerpt cause any problems in general:

```
void * fct(void * p)
{
  int i = 0;
  int * input = (int *) p;
  int * arr = malloc((*input)*sizeof(int));
  /* put something in arr */
  return (void *) arr
}

int main()
{
  /* prologue */
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
  {
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, fct, (void *) &input[i]);
  }
  /* epilogue */
}
```

What I do not actually understand and have not found an answer for is: are the the variables inside the threaded routine (`i`, `input`, `arr`) shared? The way I understand pthreads is that different copies of `fct` get called `MAX_THREADS` times, each with its own set of variables.

Comment: each thread has its own stack. Excellent pthreads tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Local automatic variables in a function are inherently thread-safe; they are allocated anew for each call of the function, whether that's in a threaded context or a recursive context or a simple call to a the function.  Global variables in general are shared — unless created as thread-local storage (TLS) or thread-specific storage (TSS — the term used in C11).  The code I see should be OK except for a memory leakage when the threads return — but the thread cleanup code isn't shown so that may be unfair.  You need to capture the return value via `pthread_join()` and release it to avoid leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The succinct answer to your question "Does the … code excerpt cause any problems in general" is "No".  As noted in various comments and answers:

> Local automatic variables in a function are inherently thread-safe; they are allocated anew for each call of the function, whether that's in a threaded context or a recursive context or a simple call to a the function. Global variables in general are shared — unless created as thread-local storage (TLS) or thread-specific storage (TSS — the term used in C11). The code [in the question] should be OK except for a memory leakage when the threads return — but the thread cleanup code isn't shown so that may be unfair. You need to capture the return value via `pthread_join()` and release it to avoid leaks.

Fleshing out the code excerpt into working code, using a mutex to show off and ensure that one thread at a time is printing its data, you could have code like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static void *fct(void *p)
{
    int number = *(int *)p;
    int *arr = malloc(number * sizeof(int));  // Error check missing!
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        arr[i] =  number + (7 * i + 5) % 11;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);   // Error check missing!
    printf("Integers %2d (%p):", number, (void *)arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        printf(" %3d", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); // Error check missing!
    return (void *)arr;
}

enum { MAX_THREADS = 10 };

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    int input[MAX_THREADS];
    int *result[MAX_THREADS];

    /* Initialization */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        input[i] = (3 * i + 2) % 13 + 1;

    /* Thread creation */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);   // Error check missing!
        printf("Launch %d: %2d\n", i, input[i]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); // Error check missing!
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, fct, (void *)&input[i]);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Oops creating thread %d\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Thread harvesting */
    for (int i = MAX_THREADS; i-- > 0; )
    {
        void *vp;
        int rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &vp);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Oops joining thread %d\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Thread %d: %2d (%p)\n", i, input[i], vp);
        result[i] = vp;
    }

    /* Finalization */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("Master - %d:", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < input[i]; j++)
            printf(" %3d", result[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
        free(result[i]);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example run

```
Launch 0:  3
Launch 1:  6
Launch 2:  9
Launch 3: 12
Integers  6 (0x7faf9ae01890):  11   7  14  10   6  13
Integers  3 (0x7faf9af00000):   8   4  11
Integers  9 (0x7faf9b800000):  14  10  17  13   9  16  12  19  15
Launch 4:  2
Integers 12 (0x7faf9b800030):  17  13  20  16  12  19  15  22  18  14  21  17
Launch 5:  5
Integers  2 (0x7faf9af00010):   7   3
Integers  5 (0x7faf9b800060):  10   6  13   9   5
Launch 6:  8
Launch 7: 11
Integers  8 (0x7faf9ae018b0):  13   9  16  12   8  15  11  18
Launch 8:  1
Integers 11 (0x7faf9b800080):  16  12  19  15  11  18  14  21  17  13  20
Launch 9:  4
Integers  1 (0x7faf9af00020):   6
Integers  4 (0x7faf9b8000b0):   9   5  12   8
Thread 9:  4 (0x7faf9b8000b0)
Thread 8:  1 (0x7faf9af00020)
Thread 7: 11 (0x7faf9b800080)
Thread 6:  8 (0x7faf9ae018b0)
Thread 5:  5 (0x7faf9b800060)
Thread 4:  2 (0x7faf9af00010)
Thread 3: 12 (0x7faf9b800030)
Thread 2:  9 (0x7faf9b800000)
Thread 1:  6 (0x7faf9ae01890)
Thread 0:  3 (0x7faf9af00000)
Master - 0:   8   4  11
Master - 1:  11   7  14  10   6  13
Master - 2:  14  10  17  13   9  16  12  19  15
Master - 3:  17  13  20  16  12  19  15  22  18  14  21  17
Master - 4:   7   3
Master - 5:  10   6  13   9   5
Master - 6:  13   9  16  12   8  15  11  18
Master - 7:  16  12  19  15  11  18  14  21  17  13  20
Master - 8:   6
Master - 9:   9   5  12   8
```

---

Full disclosure:

Tested on Mac OS X 10.11.6 with GCC 6.1.0 and Valgrind 3.12.0.SVN.  And, when run under Valgrind, it crashes.  It's not crashed when not running under Valgrind.

```
==3412== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3412== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3412== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3412== Command: ./pth37
==3412== 
Launch 0:  3
Launch 1:  6
Launch 2:  9
Launch 3: 12
Launch 4:  2
Integers  3 (0x100aaf5b0):   8   4  11
Launch 5:  5
Integers 12 (0x100aaf600):  17  13  20  16  12  19  15  22  18  14  21  17
Integers  6 (0x100aaf670):  11   7  14  10   6  13
Integers  9 (0x100aaf6d0):  14  10  17  13   9  16  12  19  15
Integers  2 (0x100aaf740):   7   3
Launch 6:  8
Integers  5 (0x100aaf790):  10   6  13   9   5
Launch 7: 11
Integers  8 (0x100aaf7f0):  13   9  16  12   8  15  11  18
Launch 8:  1
Integers 11 (0x100aaf850):  16  12  19  15  11  18  14  21  17  13  20
Launch 9:  4
==3412== 
==3412== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3412==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x700003062C1A
==3412==    at 0x10046F374: _pthread_find_thread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==3412==    by 0x10046F2CF: _pthread_lookup_thread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==3412==    by 0x10047061A: pthread_join (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==3412==    by 0x100000C3C: main (pth37.c:52)
==3412==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3412==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3412==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3412==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3412==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--3412:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
==3412== 
==3412== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3412==     in use at exit: 26,557 bytes in 196 blocks
==3412==   total heap usage: 280 allocs, 84 frees, 32,789 bytes allocated
==3412== 

Memcheck: mc_leakcheck.c:1106 (void lc_scan_memory(Addr, SizeT, Bool, Int, Int, Addr, SizeT)): Assertion 'bad_scanned_addr >= VG_ROUNDUP(start, sizeof(Addr))' failed.

host stacktrace:
==3412==    at 0x238050773: ???
==3412==    by 0x238050B9C: ???
==3412==    by 0x238050B7A: ???
==3412==    by 0x238003B86: ???
==3412==    by 0x2380033A6: ???
==3412==    by 0x238002050: ???
==3412==    by 0x238014F0D: ???
==3412==    by 0x23805D562: ???
==3412==    by 0x2380F2772: ???
==3412==    by 0x2380F287A: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=2
```

And I am puzzled by this, to be polite about it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and rather "comforting" answer if I may add. I'm not even using a mutex in my code because all I'm doing is dividing the iterations of a for loop over as many threads as I want, calculating a simple function of each element of the input array after dereferencing, putting it in the dynamically created array, and returning a pointer to the resulting array. At this point, I don't know what to do.


EDIT: I'm using MinGW x64 GCC 6.1 with default win32 threads

Comment: I used the mutex because I wanted the outputs serialized — each thread gets to print its own outputs.  (Strictly, I should be using a mutex around the main thread `printf()` in the 'thread harvesting' loop, but I get away with because I wait for the last thread to be started first, so the others are usually all done or almost done before that loop starts printing.)  I think, but I'm not quite comfortable claiming, that there's a problem with the version of Valgrind that I'm using on the Mac that I'm using, at least in the multi-threaded program.  Run outside of Valgrind, my code appears clean.

Comment: I'll try to run this code on Mac OS X and Linux and should get to the bottom of this, and I'll get back in case I find something. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't need the mutex — probably.  You should be able to adapt my code to suit your purposes.  The formulae with prime numbers etc are simply ways of making the output more interesting than `1 2 3 4`.  I am still reconfiguring my VM — my initial upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 was not a success — and haven't had a chance to run the code there, yet.

Comment: Figured out the problem, it's this careless line of code in main:
`input_s input[MAX_THREADS] = {deft_input};`

Comment: Well done!  What was the cause of the trouble?  What's the type `input_s`?  What's the `deft_input`?  It looks like you may have been initializing the array — in part.  But I don't immediately see why that was a problem.

Comment: my input struct `deft_input` contains a bunch of pointers to allocated memory which shall be the same for all threads, as well as start and stop indices that denote the limits of the for loop executed inside the `fct` and shall be different for different threads. Unfortunately, I carelessly and horrendously initialized my input structure to `{deft_input}`, or equivalently `{deft_input}, 0, 0, 0`... Embarrassing.

Comment: OK; that sort of thing will do it.  It's amazing what a little time, or someone else looking at the code, will do.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are shared between threads. So is the reference to input you are passing as parameter.

The variables you are refering to, on the other hand, are locals, allocated on the stack and are different from each other. This is not related to threads, but to the current value of the stack pointer.
The result of the malloc will be different as well, since malloc is called several times.

All this is very loosely related to threads, and several calls of your function in the same thread will behave the same memory-wise (not time-wise). There would be a slight difference concerning the local variables since stack is not shared between threads gut that is all.

Ps your code does not compile.

Comment: Maybe I miscommunicated my question: Each call of `fct` allocates some memory and keeps a handle to it, the handle has a value. Do all versions of `fct` share the same value of the pointer?

Comment: See my edit. Each call to malloc will yield a different result, thread or not thread by the way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is causing a problem.  `pthread_create` returns an error code.  From the man page:

> On success, `pthread_create()` returns 0; on error, it returns an error
>   number, and the contents of *thread are undefined.

You're not going to be able to return the pointer to your `malloc` this way.  You'll have to either have a global array of pointers that your thread can save its `malloc` result in, or you'll have to pass a pointer in as an argument.  If you have more than 1 argument you want to pass to a thread, the only way I know how to do it is by using a `struct`.

Comment: `pthread_join()` is how you collect the return value from a thread.  So, your observation is correct, but not entirely on target.  The code will leak memory unless the return values from the thread function are captured and subsequently freed.  That may not matter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Still, `pthread_join()` returns an error code (and `pthread_exit()` in the function can supply that code). As far as I know there simply isn't a way to do what he's trying to do..., which is, launch a bunch of threads, each thread `malloc`s some memory, then returns a pointer to that memory. He will need to pass in a `void**` or use a global to retain the result of `malloc` outside of the `fct` function. I assumed he expected `rc` to hold the result of the `malloc` call, perhaps that's a bad assumption.

Comment: See POSIX on [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html): —— `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);`  … On return from a successful `pthread_join()` call with a non-NULL `value_ptr` argument, the value passed to `pthread_exit()` by the terminating thread shall be made available in the location referenced by `value_ptr`. …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Touche. I was not aware that `pthread_join()` accepted any arguments. So you're saying a possible solution is he can `malloc` the memory, then call `pthread_exit` with the return value from `malloc`, then use `pthread_join`'s second argument to gather that return value? Interesting,, I was unaware of that. I've always just passed in what I needed at thread creation. Thanks for the input, I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: From [`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html): _An implicit call to `pthread_exit()` is made when a thread other than the thread in which `main()` was first invoked returns from the start routine that was used to create it. The function's return value shall serve as the thread's exit status._  In other words, the return value from `fct()` in the question becomes the exit status via `pthread_exit()` and thence `pthread_join()`.  You use `pthread_exit()` (in particular) when you want to terminate a thread without returning from the function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right on,, makes sense now. I still think from the posted code he's trying to save `malloc`'s return value in `rc`. Should've cleared that up before I posted an answer I suppose, but I was on my way out the door. And I learned things about `pthread_join` and `pthread_exit` that I didn't know before, so,, good night for me :)

Comment: @yano "So you're saying a possible solution is he can `malloc` the memory, then call `pthread_exit` with the return value from `malloc`, then use `pthread_join`'s second argument to gather that return value? ". That's exactly what I'm doing. But I'm getting the SIGSEGV almost at the beginning of the function called using `pthread_create`.

Comment: only thing I see in `fct` that could be seg faulting is if your `p` parameter is NULL, which will cause the `*input` dereference to seg fault. Some more code would be helpful (declaration and initialization of `input` for instance).